# Append/Remove to the end of bootstrap-select on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) on a site with multi-select functionality. I would like to preserve the order in which the items are selected by the user meaning, let's say that I have a list like this:

```
<select name="selValue" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
</select>
```

If the user clicks on the items in the order of Val 4, Val 2, Val 3, Va1, I want the items to appear in that order in the field.

That's not the default behavior of the plugin unfortunately. Anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: I put 100eur it is possible :) You better check its [docs](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/)

Comment: Have you looked at this example. It may help you with your query https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/